# CSS3 selectors not working in FF and Opera?

Tags: css, richfaces

I'd like to style one span element generated by Rich faces:

```
<td class="rf-tb-itm" id="j_idt7:logoutLink_itm">
      <span class="topmenulink" id="j_idt7:logoutLink">Logout</span>
</td>
```

I can't match for the whole id because the part before the semicolon can differ. For testing I wrote

```
span[id="j_idt7:logoutLink"]  {
   padding:2pt 10pt !important;
   border:1px solid transparent;
   color:grey;
}
```

and it matches.
This matches too:

```
td > span  {
   padding:2pt 10pt !important;
   border:1px solid transparent;
   color:grey;
}
```

But why does not match this (in latest Firefox and Opera)

```
span[id*="logoutLink"]  {
   padding:2pt 10pt !important;
   border:1px solid transparent;
   color:grey;
}
```

or this?

```
span[id$="logoutLink"]  {
   padding:2pt 10pt !important;
   border:1px solid transparent;
   color:grey;
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Considering this table, it should: http://www.css3.info/modules/selector-compat/ .  Do you see rules blocs in you browser, is it really interpreted ?

Comment: I am pretty sure it should work in those browsers.

Comment: @sinsedrix If I debug it with Firebug, the CSS setting doesn't appear. So it doesn't match. But when I compare it with the compatibly table, FF and Opera should support it. 
Maybe RichFaces makes something odd so that the browser doesn't recognize the CSS, but I'm not sure what this could be.

Comment: If your CSS doesn't appear in firebug it means it's not well interpreted. Maybe there are some parasite characters due to the file generation. Check encoding, endlines, ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know what's going on. It's an RichFaces problem. The CSS EL Parser doesn't recognize CSS3. See the JBoss output:

```
08:54:18,235 WARNING [org.richfaces.log.Resource] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-6) Problem parsing 'css/default.ecss' resource: Error in attribute selector. Invalid token "*". Was expecting one of: <S>, "=", "]", "~=", "|=".
08:54:18,236 WARNING [org.richfaces.log.Resource] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-6) Problem parsing 'css/default.ecss' resource: Ignoring the whole rule.
```

It works when I use a "real" CSS file and not this EL CSS.